# Splitting the first part of the string using vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

Below is the perfect working code, when i googled for splitting the first part of the string with a delimiter.

But i have a problem because, this code works only when the target framework is 4
How can i convert this code, where it will run in target framework 2

```
    Public Shared Function FirstFromSplit(ByVal source As String, ByVal delimiter As String) As String
        Dim i = source.IndexOf(delimiter)

       Return If(i = -1, source, source.Substring(0, i))

    End Function
```

Comment: What makes you think this code won't run under .NET 4?

Comment: why not just use `return source.split(delimiter)`?

Comment: @JayRiggs It works in framework 4 but does not work in framework 2.

Comment: What goes wrong in .NET 2? It should be fine...

Comment: I don't think `If` existed until .Net 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as know both string-methods exists in 2.0, so I guess it's the return-statement that gives troubles.
Try re-writing it in the old style.

```
Public Shared Function FirstFromSplit(ByVal source As String, ByVal delimiter As String) As String 
     Dim i = source.IndexOf(delimiter) 

     If i < 0 Then
       return source
     Else
       return source.Substring(0, i)
     End if
End Function
```

Comment: wouldn't `return source.split(delimiter)(0)` accomplish the same thing? what am I missing? **Edit: I guess the main difference is split doesn't work(very easily at least) with strings as delimiters.